# Unit testing KeyboardEvent returning "isTrusted: false" and "Cannot read property 'nextElementSibling' of null"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, keyboard-events

I have a function that is triggered via `keydown.enter` and will focus on the next available element, however I cannot get the test to accept my fake KeyboardEvent...

```
@ViewChild('btnOne') btnOne: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
@ViewChild('btnTwo') btnTwo: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

myFunct(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
  const next = <HTMLElement>evt.srcElement.nextElementSibling;
  next.focus();
}
```

Test:

```
it('Should shift focus from btnOne to btnTwo', () => {
  const b1 = component.btnOne.nativeElement;
  const b2 = component.btnTwo.nativeElement;

  const button2 = {nodeName:'BUTTON'}
  const button1 = {nodeName:'BUTTON', nextElementSibling: button2};

  const evtObj = {'code': 'Enter', srcElement: button1);
  const kbEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown.enter', evtObj);

  focusSpy = spyOn(b2, 'focus'); // Spy on focus for 2nd button to be focused
  b1.focus(); // Manually apply focus to 1st button so it will progress from here

  component.myFunct(kbEvent); // I get the failures here (see below)

  expect(b2.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

The test error with the message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextElementSibling' of null

I have also printed out the `evt` as it comes from the test into the function itself:

> KeyboardEvent{isTrusted: false}

I have searched for the `isTrusted` issue and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101648/angular-4-unit-test-for-keyboardevent), but I couldn't resolve my issue with their answer...

Comment: Since the event is instantiated by yourself, how is it supposed to refer to an element?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @YoukouleleY

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that I am not required to use `evt: KeyboardEvent` in the args for the function itself?

Comment: You are constructing an event yourself with `new KeyboardEvent('keydown.enter', event);`, then why do you expect it to have a value in `srcElement`?

Comment: Are `evtObj` and `event` supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: @YoukouleleY -Yes they are, I have updated to both be `evtObj` now. Apologies.

Comment: Dit it fix the problem?

Comment: @YoukouleleY - No, that was simply a typo in the question, not present in my actual code. Sorry

Comment: I am facing the same thing I think. Could you solve this or work it around ?