# Angular: How test keyboard event in jasmine unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, directive, keyboard-events

I've created custom directive to populate auto dash. Here is full custom directive code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auto-dash-directive). May i know how to test following lines from **mask.ts** in jasmine (unit test)?

**mask.ts**

```
@HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    let trimmed = input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

**mask.spec.ts**

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <input type="text" dobMask />
  `,
})
class TestdobMaskComponent {}

describe('dobMask', () => {
  let component: TestdobMaskComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestdobMaskComponent>;
  let inputEl: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestdobMaskComponent],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestdobMaskComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
  });
  it('should auto populate dash when reach 6 characters', () => {
    const input = inputEl.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101648/angular-4-unit-test-for-keyboardevent

Comment: @Ali yes. I tried few methods as well. None of them working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
it('should auto populate dash when reach 6 characters', () => {
    const input = inputEl.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: ' ' }));
    // put a console.log in onKeyDown to make sure it is triggered.
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // grab a new reference
    const newInputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')) as HTMLInputElement;
    // trimmed is a local variable to the function so I don't know how you're going to test it
   // expect the space got trimmed
    expect(newInputEl.nativeElement.value).toEqual(""); 
  });
```

Comment: input returning `true` now. How I can acheive `let trimmed = input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');`

Comment: Check my edit, trimmed is a local variable so it will be difficult to test.